# Redirect .aspx url to one without it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I would like to get my URL redirect from a legacy URL with .aspx to one without it using IIS.

Example:

1. https://www.example.com/category.aspx to https://www.example.com/category
2. https://www.example.com/category.aspx?type=test to https://www.example.com/category?type=test

Can we achieve the redirect of the above type using IIS? Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in IIS with [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module. You can configure it in IIS manager. Some examples are in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). This redirecting rule should work.

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect from aspx" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.+?).aspx" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```